# Looped SQL queries with 2 variables

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I have a table (tags) with 3 fields, activityID, placeID, tagID (and a 4th, ID as PKey). I want to search through this table using 2 arrays, one of places and one of tags. For each match I want to return the activityID. I then want to used this activityID list in another table (activity) with each of the same array of PlaceIDs. I started to put this together as loops but I see lots of things saying not to do that. I was thinking I need to use a temp table but this also might not be required. I'm also struggling to do it with loops anyway so rather than struggle to make something which is poor practice anyway I thought I'd post the general idea to see if somebody could point me in the right direction... This code is not working but shows the general idea..EDIT... I'm only looking to resolve the loop in the first section, the second section I need to leave as a loop

```
$places = array("London","Madrid","Paris","Rome"); 
$tags = array("Shopping","Sight","Bar","Club");
$num_places = count($places);
$num_tags = count($tags);

/* I want to remove the loop from this section */
$counterP = 0; 
while($counterP <= ($num_places)) {
  $counterT = 0; 
  while($counterT <= ($num_tags)) {
    $conn->query('INSERT INTO temp (activityID)
    SELECT activityID, placeID
    FROM tags
    WHERE placeID = "'.$place[$counterP].'" AND tagID = "'.$tag[$counterT].'"');
  $counterT++;
  }
$counterP++;
}

/* This section will stay in a loop */
$counterP = 0; 
while($counterP <= ($num_places)) {
$sql_interests = 'SELECT a.summary, a.image, a.link
  FROM activity a 
  LEFT JOIN temp t
  ON t.activityID = a.activityID 
  WHERE a.placeID = "'.$place[$counterP].'"';

  $interests = array();
  $interests_result = $conn->query($sql_interests);
  if ( !empty($interests_result)) {
    while($interests_row = $interests_result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $interests[] = array($interests_row["summary"],$intersts_row["image"],$interests_row["link"]);
    }
    /* do stuff with data */
  }
  $counterP++;
}
```

Comment: can you make a sqlfiddle of the 2 or 3 tables? Someone will bang it out in mysql only, as 1 option

Comment: Sure will do.....back in a min....

Comment: Then you need to specify what a "match" means. So is it London is a match, or is it (London and Shopping) or () ... etc. Parentheses matter

Comment: OK so here's an sqlfiddle with a few items in each table.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bc650c/3


So I have an array of places and and array of tags. I want to find all the combinations in my tags table and get the accociated activity for each match. I then use this list of matched activities in a new query to get all the associated data from the 'activity' table. FYI I will need to use a loop for the second part as I will be building my HTML in sections by placeID. So it's mainly the first part...

Comment: so let's say I have 3 places and 3 tags. What is the permutation count you are expecting for a result

Comment: updated fiddle, some data was wrong... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/86bc95 tables still the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mysql only approach. The where clause filters tags with an in clause, and the join gets you to the activity table. The `a` and `t` are just aliases for either easier reading or the lazy (like me)

```
select a.* 
from activity a
join tags t
on t.activityID=a.activityId
where t.tagID in ('sightseeing','parks')
and t.placeID in ('Istanbul','Paris');

+----+------------+---------+---------------------------+
| ID | activityID | placeID | summary                   |
+----+------------+---------+---------------------------+
|  4 | 444        | Paris   | See Arc D'Triumph         |
|  6 | 666        | Paris   | See Eifel Tower           |
|  8 | 888        | Paris   | Walk through Central Park |
+----+------------+---------+---------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks @Drew (again :-) )! One key question.... can i use my arrays so its `where t.tagID in $tags`

Comment: if in PHP you create such a $sqlString with concatenation, then yes. I am **not** talking about PHP binding with prepared statements, but just PHP concat with `.`

Answer (score 2):

As I am currently limited to cell phone access, I can only suggest you to do following things:

1. Join both arrays with "','" as delimiter.
2. Write where clause using IN() function. Like: Where placeID IN('London','Madrid','Paris','Rome') And tagID IN(...)

This should give your required result.

Comment: Can I write  'WHERE placeID IN $places'  ?